javascript code to select a fixed number of questions from json file
I have the code for a MCQ app that uses HTML, CSS, and JS. The code asks all the questions that are in the array object (which in this case is 8). However, I want the app to select only five random questions from the list of questions.
const quizData = [
    {
        question: "What is the most used programming language in 2019?",
        a: "Java",
        b: "C",
        c: "Python",
        d: "JavaScript",
        correct: "d",
    },
    {
        question: "Who is the President of US?",
        a: "Florin Pop",
        b: "Donald Trump",
        c: "Ivan Saldano",
        d: "Mihai Andrei",
        correct: "b",
    },
    {
        question: "What does HTML stand for?",
        a: "Hypertext Markup Language",
        b: "Cascading Style Sheet",
        c: "Jason Object Notation",
        d: "Helicopters Terminals Motorboats Lamborginis",
        correct: "a",
    },
    {
        question: "What year was JavaScript launched?",
        a: "1996",
        b: "1995",
        c: "1994",
        d: "none of the above",
        correct: "b",
    },
    {
        question: "Which is the largest animal in the world?",
        a: "Shark",
        b: "Blue Whale",
        c: "Elephant",
        d: "Giraffe",
        correct: "b",
    },
    {
        question: "Which is the smallest country in the world?",
        a: "Vatican City",
        b: "Bhutan",
        c: "Nepal",
        d: "Sri Lanka",
        correct: "a",
    },
    {
        question: "Which is the largest desert in the world?",
        a: "Kalahari",
        b: "Gobi",
        c: "Sahara",
        d: "Antarctica",
        correct: "d",
    },
    {
        question: "Which is the smallest continent in the world?",
        a: "Asia",
        b: "Australia",
        c: "Arctic",
        d: "Africa",
        correct: "b",
    },
];

const quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
const answerEls = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
const questionEl = document.getElementById("question");
const a_text = document.getElementById("a_text");
const b_text = document.getElementById("b_text");
const c_text = document.getElementById("c_text");
const d_text = document.getElementById("d_text");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

let currentQuiz = 0;
let score = 0;

loadQuiz();

function loadQuiz() {
    deselectAnswers();

    const currentQuizData = quizData[currentQuiz];

    questionEl.innerText = currentQuizData.question;
    a_text.innerText = currentQuizData.a;
    b_text.innerText = currentQuizData.b;
    c_text.innerText = currentQuizData.c;
    d_text.innerText = currentQuizData.d;
}

function getSelected() {
    let answer = undefined;

    answerEls.forEach((answerEl) => {
        if (answerEl.checked) {
            answer = answerEl.id;
        }
    });

    return answer;
}

function deselectAnswers() {
    answerEls.forEach((answerEl) => {
        answerEl.checked = false;
    });
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // check to see the answer
    const answer = getSelected();

    if (answer) {
        if (answer === quizData[currentQuiz].correct) {
            score++;
        }

        currentQuiz++;
        if (currentQuiz < quizData.length) {
            loadQuiz();
        } else {
            quiz.innerHTML = `
                <h2>You answered correctly at ${score}/${quizData.length} questions.</h2>

                <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button>
            `;
        }
    }
});

I know that I can use the random function like this within some kind of loop:
Math.floor(Math.random() * quizData.length);

But I am not sure how to use this within the code.
The project is here: codepen

Before you actually ask a randomly picked question, make sure that it has not already been asked before. You could maintain an array whose n-th entry is true if question number n has already been asked.

You don't have any JSON in your question - you have an array of objects.  Please refer to What is JSON

Two choices:  build an array of questions or build an array of indexes to the questions.   First is probably easier to visualise: you create a new array and copy in questions until you have 5 - then use that new array in your quiz.  2nd is similar but the quiz uses the index-array to locate the actual question.

@HeikoTheißen Please define a randomly picked question?

A question in the array whose position is determined by a random function.

You can shallow copy the array and splice items randomly from it:


const arr = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8" ]; // simplified for demo

const copy = arr.slice();

const result = Array.from({length:5}, (_, i) => copy.splice(Math.random() * copy.length | 0, 1)[0]);
 
console.log(result);



You can actually do that with the original array if you don't need it intact after the selection.

Rename quizData to quizSource and create a new array quizData - then your existing code will work as-is (using quizData).
Copy questions from quizSource -> quizData at the start of the quiz.
As a first step, simply loop until you have enough questions:


let quizSource = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8" ]; // simplified for demo
let quizData = [];

for (let i=0;i<5;++i)
  quizData.push(quizSource[i]);
 
console.log(quizData);



Next step it to determine random questions, but works essentially the same way, copy questions to quizData from quizSource.
Using your Math.floor(Math.random() * quizSource.length) to determine a random index, you can then use .includes to determine if it's already included
if (quizData.includes(idx))
  // already have this idx

which can be implemented in a while loop to keep getting indexes until you hit one that you haven't previous used.
NB: the for limit must be less than or equal to the source.length otherwise you get an infinite loop.  Always add limit checks (not included here for clarity)


var quizSource = [
    {Name:"Q1"}, {Name:"Q2"}, {Name:"Q3"}, {Name:"Q4"}, {Name:"Q5"}, {Name:"Q6"}, {Name:"Q7"}, {Name:"Q8"} 
]; // simplified for demo
let quizData = [];

function newQuizData() {
  quizData = [];
  for (let i=0;i<5;++i)
  {
    let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quizSource.length);
    while (quizData.includes(idx))
      idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quizSource.length);

    quizData.push(quizSource[idx]);
  }
}
 
newQuizData();
console.log(quizData);

newQuizData();
console.log(quizData);
view browser console for results



Then call newQuziData() at the start of your quiz

So, I have been working on this, but I don't get the questions. Instead I get a string that says 'Question'. https://codepen.io/Stac-Flo/pen/QWPJYOb

Shallow copying arrays these days is done using const copyArr = [...origArr].

When developing with javascript - be sure to keep the browser console open to see errors - your codepen has a typo on the first line:  newQuziData is not defined.  You get Question because that's your HTML and the js fails (does nothing) so doesn't replace it.   Fixing the typo (and corresponding order - ensure quizSource is first) and removing the i=0..5 which changes the data and your code works fine

As @connexo correctly points out, there are plenty of other ways to get a list of questions.  As you'll see from the way I've worded this answer, I prefer the progressive approach - ie start with the basics (and understand them) and then move to the next step / level of difficulty.

I update the loadQuiz function
function loadQuiz() {
    deselectAnswers();
    selectedElements.length = 0;
    const selectedElements = [];
    const numElementsToSelect = 5;
    while (selectedElements.length < numElementsToSelect) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quizData.length);
        const randomElement = quizData[randomIndex];
    
        if (!selectedElements.includes(randomElement)) {
            selectedElements.push(randomElement);
        }
    }

    if (currentQuiz < numElementsToSelect) {
        const currentQuizData = selectedElements[currentQuiz];

        questionEl.innerText = currentQuizData.question;
        a_text.innerText = currentQuizData.a;
        b_text.innerText = currentQuizData.b;
        c_text.innerText = currentQuizData.c;
        d_text.innerText = currentQuizData.d;
    }
}

and in submitBtn EventListener update if condition:
// numElementsToSelect instead of quizData.length
  if (currentQuiz < numElementsToSelect) {
            loadQuiz();
      }

